# Gui where you can paste a text with a lot of lines

Tags: java

I would like to make a gui where after i click a button i can paste a text with a lot of lines and submit that text.

Example of the code i have for create the button:

```
public class SimpleGui implements ActionListener {
 JButton button;
 SimpleGui g;
public static void main (String[] args) {
    SimpleGui g = new SimpleGui();
    g.go();
}

public void go(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    button = new JButton("Insert Player");

    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    button.setText("Now paste the data! "); 
}
```

}

Now where i have `button.setText("Now paste the data! ");`, what i want is to:

1. Create some kind of widget that allow me to insert  20 lines of text i've copied from a .txt document.
   2) receive and manage the data that the user did put on the widget.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please elaborate with an example.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about JTextArea? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html

Comment: 1) Use JTextArea.  2) Get the text from the text area and write it to a file, a database, the cloud, or trace the data with your finger on the sand of a beach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your question is unclear but probably you're asking about a component where you can set your text. Use `JTextArea` as follows:

```
JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea("The initial text");
your_container.add(textarea);
```

Then whenever you want to get the text from your text area, use:

```
String data = textarea.getText();
```

If at runtime you want to set the textarea to some data you can:

```
textarea.setText("Your data here");
```

**EDIT :**

After the OP added the code, I think this is what he wants to achieve:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
class SimpleGui implements ActionListener 
{
JButton button;
SimpleGui g;
JTextArea textarea;
JFrame frame;
String data;
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    SimpleGui g = new SimpleGui();
    g.go();
}
public void go()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    button = new JButton("Insert Player");
    textarea = new JTextArea("Paste data here!");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Insert Player"))
    {
        button.setText("Now paste the data!");
        frame.getContentPane().add(textarea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Now paste the data!"))
    {
        data = textarea.getText();
        System.out.println(data);
    }
}
}
```

Your text data is in the `data` variable. You can use it as you like. I've simply demonstrated that by printing it.

Comment: Nice ty,  now Where will I have the data in order to send the data to an object?

Comment: @UcanDoIt Edited again. Please accept as the answer.